# MVC 4 PartialViewResult return PartialView Calls Wrong View (URL)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm fairly new to MVC and JQuery. I'm using MVC 4.  I have an index view that I can edit the fields on. I want to be able to add a blank row at the bottom of the listing to be used for adding new rows. My work so far is based on this example in MVC 2 : http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Here's my index view:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<h3 style="margin-top: 1px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="selectedConditionID" value="@ViewBag.SelectedConditionID" />
    <input type="hidden" name="isCore" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Add Condition Detail", "BlankEditorRow", null, new { id="addItem"})
</h3>
<div class="table" id="editorRows"> 
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; ++i) {
    ViewBag.i = i;
    Html.RenderPartial("_ConditionDetailEditorRow", Model[i]);
}
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Condition Library", null, "Home")
</div>
```

}

Here's the partial view:

```
    <div class="editorRow">
@if (@ViewBag.i == 0) {
    <div class="header-row">
        <div class="header-cell">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StackRank)</div>
        <div class="header-cell">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)</div> ...
        <div class="header-cell">Options</div>
    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    int i = @ViewBag.i;
    <div  class="body-cell">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StackRank)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StackRank)
    </div>
    <div  class="body-cell">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ID)
    </div> ...
    <div  class="body-cell">
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=Model.ID })
    </div>
}
```

Here's the JQuery in my Index view that is supposed to be causing the blank row to be added to the end of the index listing:

```
$(function () {
    $("#addItem").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's the controller method:

```
public PartialViewResult BlankEditorRow()
    {
        ViewBag.i = 0;
        return PartialView("_ConditionDetailEditorRow", new Condition_Details());
    }
```

Here's the problem: when I click the "Add Condition Detail" action link on the Index page I get a page of the partial view only (...//localhost:56213/ConfigurationUI/ConditionDetails/BlankEditorRow/addItem).

What I want is a blank row to appear at the bottom on the Index page.  I assume the URL should be something like: ...//localhost:56213/ConfigurationUI/ConditionDetails/Index/addItem.

Now I suspect that my JQuery script is not firing, but don't know why?

What's wrong?

Thanks!

## I worked out a solution:

### I put the whole table in the partial view:

**Revised Index View**

```
<div id="condition_detailsList">
     @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ConditionDetailsEdit", Model); }
</div>
```

**Revised Partial View**

```
<table id="condition_detailsList">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].StackRank)
        </th>...

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="editorRows">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; ++i) {
            <tr style="margin:0; padding:0; border:0;">
                <td> <div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].StackRank)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].StackRank)
                </div> </td>...

            </tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID, new { @id = "hID" + i })...
        }
</tbody>
```

### From the Index view using Ajax I called a post method in the controller

```
    $(function () {
    $('#addItem').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("GetNewRow", "ConditionDetails"))",
            data: { "conditionID": cID },
            success: function (condition_detailsListPlusNewRow) {
                //initialize fields...
```

### In the controller I returned the new row to the partial view

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetNewRow(int conditionID) //, List<Condition_Details> conditionDetails)
    {
        //you must initial the index view here, then...

        //retrieve the list, add a new row and return the partial view
        var condition_details = db.Condition_Details.Where(x => x.Condition_ID ==       conditionID).OrderBy(x => x.StackRank).ThenBy(x => x.ID).ToList();

        Condition_Details conditionDetail = new Condition_Details();
        List<Condition_Details> condition_detailsPlusNewRow = new List<Condition_Details>();
        foreach (var row in condition_details)
        {
            conditionDetail = row;
            condition_detailsPlusNewRow.Add(conditionDetail);
        }

        Condition_Details newRow = new Condition_Details();
        newRow.Condition_ID = conditionDetail.Condition_ID;
        newRow.Condition = conditionDetail.Condition;
        newRow.StackRank = conditionDetail.StackRank + 1;
        condition_detailsPlusNewRow.Add(newRow);


        return PartialView("_ConditionDetailsEdit", condition_detailsPlusNewRow);
    }
```

Comment: Very good solution. It worked for me and I found this the best example for what I needed to do. if you need to render your partial view before you have a Model result you can do this:     @if (Model != null)
    {
      Html.Raw(Model.Name);
    }

Comment: I had the same problem, hoping to help someone with this comment : I had a form in side a form, which made jquery return a connection page. I just moved my form so they don't overlap and it works instantly. Rookie mistake for sure but still hard to pinpoint on the go.